# sorting not working properly angular 4

Tags: arrays, angular, sorting

I have various tables and I'm trying to sort table using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-order-pipe. I followed their documentation and everything works fine except it is not sorting correctly the columns (here in the example, 'Rank' column)

For example I have a response like this:

```
"collection": [
            {
                "name": "John",
                "age" : "25",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "final_rank": "150"
                    }
                ]
            }
        {
                "name": "Mark",
                "age" : "19",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "final_rank": "254"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Here's my HTML:

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th (click)="setOrder('name')">Name</th>
          <th (click)="setOrder('age')">Age</th>
          <th (click)="setOrder('final_rank')">Rank</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let Data of collection | orderBy: order:reverse:'case-insensitive'">
          <td class="text-truncate">{{Data.name}}</td>
          <td class="text-truncate">{{Data.age}}</td>
          <td class="text-truncate" *ngIf="!isArray(Data.details)">
            <tr> {{Data.details.final_rank}} </tr>
          </td>
          <td class="text-truncate" *ngIf="isArray(Data.details)"><tr *ngFor="let rankData of Data.details"> {{rankData.final_rank}} </tr></td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

component.ts

```
  order;
  reverse = false;

  isArray(obj: any) {
    return Array.isArray(obj)
  }
  getData() {
    this.http.get('**')
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
      setOrder(value) {
         if (this.order === value) {
           this.reverse = !this.reverse;
         }
         this.order = value;
         console.log(this.order);
       }
```

Comment: Could you post all of your `component.ts` file? I don't understand what the `setOrder` function does.

Comment: @KylePfromer I added component.ts code. Please check. I followed the package I mentioned in the question and their documentation to implement this sorting

Comment: The problem is most likely that details is  an array which contains object and the rank is part of those objects. How should the ordering be implemented? I suspect that the sort pipe cannot handle that. You would probably have to transform your model to include the rank on the top level in order for it to be usable for sorting. But for that you need to define how you find out the rank (is it the rank from the first element, the sum of all ranks, the min/max rank, average etc.).

Comment: @tomvangreen yeah I guess you are right. Rank will be from the first element. I can retrieve Data.details[0].final_rank. But How would I implement sorting to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you try to sort by a field that is inside of an array of the actual object. I suspect that your library doesn't know how to do the sorting (and that probably rightly so). So what you should do is to transform your data in a format, where it can be sorted.

At some point in your application you have the data:

```
const originalData = [{
  'name': 'John',
  'age': '25',
  'details': [
    {
      'final_rank': '150'
    }
  ]
},
{
  'name': 'Mark',
  'age': '19',
  'details': [
    {
      'final_rank': '254'
    }
  ]
}];
```

Whata you want to do now is to take that data and to convert it to something else. In this example I want to get the max `final_rank` value of any of the `details` items. That max value will be used for sorting. You might want to use another way of defining what value to use, but for this example the max value should do fine.

We can use a map function to transform each value of your original data:

````
const mappedData = originalData.map(item => ({
  // This will do a shallow copy of all the fields of the original object
  ...item,
  // With reduce we can easily find the max ```final_rank``` value
  maxRank: item.details.reduce(
    // +current.final_rank converts the string to a number
    (max, current) => +current.final_rank > max ? current.final_rank : max,
    0
  )
}));
````

This should yield a new array which should look the same as your original data, except for an additional maxRank field on the root object.

The resulting  object would look something like this:

```
const mappedData = [{
  'name': 'John',
  'age': '25',
  'maxRank': 150,
  'details': [
    {
      'final_rank': '150'
    }
  ]
},
{
  'name': 'Mark',
  'age': '19',
  'maxRank': 254,
  'details': [
    {
      'final_rank': '254'
    }
  ]
}];
```

Now you should be able to do sorting based on the maxRank field.

Comment: That means I should also retrieve data in table from mappedData?

Comment: exactly. mappedData should be used in the ngFor directive. you need to define a field for it on your component

Comment: I did the same. I got this mappedData with maxRank and also retrieved data from mappedData. And applied sorting. but the sorting is not working on that column again

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uw8dce here's the sample. Can you please check

Comment: actually that's working. I used Number () for maxRank. Thanks a lot. Please upvote my question if you think it helps others.